# Color two html boxes differently from secondary form

Tags: javascript

I have an html form. I have a custom pop-up form with colors. I want to click on one box and select a color, then click on the second box and pick a second different color. It works for passing the color back to the main page but it changes both boxes to the same color. When I click on the second box, it changes both boxes to the same color too.  I tried to add another function for the second box but it still colors both boxes.

I think the problem is the window.addeventlistener. I've tried a bunch of different ways with all new variables in the second set and have not resolved the issue. 
Your help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10,45px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
 /* bottom: 0;
  right: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;*/
}

.form-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
.colorme {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 100%;
} 
.color-box {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }

</style>

 <body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var colorcode = ""
            let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".colorme");

        Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
        box.addEventListener("click", function() {
        colorcode = (this.classList[1])  //this gets the hex of the color selected
        document.getElementById("color-box").style.backgroundColor=colorcode;
    closeForm();
    }); 
  });
}); 
//try to just color the second box
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var colorcode = ""
            let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".colorme");

        Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
        box.addEventListener("click", function() {
        colorcode = (this.classList[1])  //this gets the hex of the color selected
        document.getElementById("color-box2").style.backgroundColor=colorcode;
    closeForm();
    }); 
  });
}); 


function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
    </script>

        <form id = "inputform">
            <table> 
                     <tr> <td>
                     <div class="input-color">
                        <div id="color-box" class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;" onclick="openForm()"></div>
                    </div></td>
                    <tr><td>
                    <div class="input-color">
                        <div id="color-box2" class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;" onclick="openForm()"></div>
                    </div></td></tr>
            </table>

<!--pop up form here-->
            <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                <form class="form-container">
    <h5>Color Picker</h5>
<div class="wrapper">
<!--<div class="chartmobile" style="height:630px;width:678px;display:inline-block;">-->
    <div class="colorme_2 #ffebee" style="background: #ffebee"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #ffcdd2" style="background: #ffcdd2"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #ef9a9a" style="background: #ef9a9a"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #e57373" style="background: #e57373"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #ef5350" style="background: #ef5350"><span class="code"></span></div>   

    <div class="colorme #f44336" style="background: #f44336"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #e53935" style="background: #e53935"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #d32f2f" style="background: #d32f2f"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #c62828" style="background: #c62828"><span class="code"></span></div>
    <div class="colorme #b71c1c" style="background: #b71c1c"><span class="code"></span></div>

</div>

    </form>
        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work no matter how many color boxes you have. I also add a disclaimer that this might not be perfect but it works [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crumdev/qx21u5k3/5/)

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Load all color-boxes into an array of objects
        let colorBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('color-box');
        var clicked;

        // Add the onclick events on each one.
        for (var i = 0; i < colorBoxes.length; i++) {
            colorBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                // store the id of the clicked color-box div to reference later
                clicked = this.id;
                console.log(clicked + " was clicked...");
                openForm();
            });
        }

        var colorcode = "";

        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".colorme");

        Array.from(boxes, function (box) {
            box.addEventListener("click", function () {
                colorcode = (this.classList[1])  //this gets the hex of the color selected
                // Now use the id of the clicked element to apply the style
                document.getElementById(clicked).style.backgroundColor = colorcode;
                closeForm();
            });
        });
    });

    function openForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
    }

    function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: To add and explanation of why your current code is not working is you added 2 event listeners to your boxes with class of .colorme. Because both event listeners are for clicks and are targeting the same objects to be clicked it is triggering both at the same time. Your event listener to color box1 gets triggered and the listener to color box 2 gets triggered.

My code adds the listener once then passes the ID of the clicked object dynamically so only the object intended gets changed.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works exactly how I want it to. Many hours of frustration and you've solved it in such a short time.  I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: I forgot to mention you should take off the onclick="openForm()" from those color-box elements with my code since I'm already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

> "It works for passing the color back to the main page but it changes both boxes to the same color. When I click on the second box, it changes both boxes to the same color too."

Well, since the click event fires both event listeners, you would expect both boxes to get colored by the same color which has already been selected. You could choose to have two separate color lists for coloring each of the two boxes, or put the code for coloring the boxes in separate functions and call the appropriate function depending on which box was clicked. Like so :

```
<script>
    function colorFirstBox() {
        openForm();
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var colorcode = ""
        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".colorme");

        Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
        box.addEventListener("click", function() {
        colorcode = (this.classList[1])  //this gets the hex of the color selected
        document.getElementById("color-box").style.backgroundColor=colorcode;
        closeForm();
        }); 
   });
}); 
</script>
<table> 
                 <tr> <td>
                 <div class="input-color">
                    <div id="color-box" class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;" onclick="colorFirstBox()"></div>
                </div></td>
                <tr><td>
                <div class="input-color">
                    <div id="color-box2" class="color-box" style="background-color: #FF850A;" onclick="colorSecondBox()"></div>
                </div></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Do the same for the second box. This code might not be 100% bug-free as I'm responding early in the morning but this is how you might go about doing it.